# Absolute Position of Chart Using VBA

Tags: vba, charts, absolute

I can use VBA to create a clustured column charty using the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
```

However this is normally positioned in the centre of my screen. I can have it moved using code such as the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -650.4545669291
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -295.9091338583
```

However this is only relative to its original position. Is it possible to set it that will always be positioned at a certain pixels or cell number? In other words can I code VBA to have create the chart in a certain position on the worksheet?

Comment: On little addition to the previous answer:
The position will only be set accurately when the active window is not zoomed in or out. So make sure that ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100 before you set the .Left and .Top-properties.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `.Top` and `.Left` properties
e.g

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1")
    .Left = Range("C10").Left
    .Top = Range("C10").Top
End With
```