# VBA Position Chart in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, charts

I am trying to add a chart to a worksheet and then position it according to a certain range of cells. I am using the .top, .left, etc. functions and it keeps giving me an error that my object does not support the method being used. What am I doing wrong?! Here is my code:

```
Sub AddCharts()

Range("O1").Select

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrows = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TraceTable")
Set chrteit = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

With chrteit
.ChartType = xlXYScatter
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = sh.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(lastrows, 6))
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = sh.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(lastrows, 7))

    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "EIT"
    .Height = Range("N2:N14").Height
    .Width = Range("N2:T2").Width
    .Top = Range("N2").Top
    .Left = Range("N2").Left
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, the `Chart` object doesn't have `Height`, `Width`, `Top` or `Left` properties, that's what it's complaining about.

Comment: How would make it have those properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute Position of Chart Using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028126/absolute-position-of-chart-using-vba)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To continue on from my comment below the original post, try replacing:

```
.Height = Range("N2:N14").Height
.Width = Range("N2:T2").Width
.Top = Range("N2").Top
.Left = Range("N2").Left
```

with:

```
.Parent.Height = Range("N2:N14").Height
.Parent.Width = Range("N2:T2").Width
.Parent.Top = Range("N2").Top
.Parent.Left = Range("N2").Left
```

Comment: Works perfectly! But can you explain why there's a difference in using parent and not?

Comment: @art123456: The chart itself is just a code object (`Chart`). To represent it in the spreadsheet, it's added to a container (`ChartObject`), which has these properties since it has to be positioned somewhere. It is actually the chart *object* that is embedded in the worksheet, and the chart object contains the chart.

Answer (score 5):

A `Chart` doesn't have the `.Top`, `.Left`, etc., properties, but it's parent container, the `ChartObject` does have those properties.

So instead of `.Height =` do `.Parent.Height =`, etc.

```
.Parent.Height = Range("N2:N14").Height
.Parent.Width = Range("N2:T2").Width
.Parent.Top = Range("N2").Top
.Parent.Left = Range("N2").Left
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could also make your answer correct as well but I can only choose one. Although I very much appreciate the help :

Comment: You can simply upvote this one if it is helpful.  Technically you *can* un-accept the other and accept this instead, but I wouldn't ask you to do that.