# Defining new chart a location in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am adding a new chart and would like to define its location.
I hav tried several approaches with top and left, but with no success.
this is my code:

```
Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(unit)
Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

With chrt
    'Data?
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).name = "=""Scatter Chart"""
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = x
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = y


    'Location
    'DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE
    '.location xlLocationAsObject doesn't work!
    'Titles
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = name
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "X values"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Y values"
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

    'Formatting
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
    .HasLegend = False
End With
```

Comment: Check out these excellent answers from [Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ResizeAndMoveAChart.html) and this one [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21028840/4717755](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21028840/4717755)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to set the cell that you want to move your chart to. Just add this outside your loop

```
sh.ChartObjects.Left = sh.Range("A1")
sh.ChartObjects.Top = sh.Range("A1")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried  - getting "method or data member not found"

Comment: Ok. do you only have the one graph on the sheet or are you going to have multiple?

Comment: I will have multiple.

Comment: Have a look again at my answer. I have updated it. This will move all chars to the cell a1. If you want to move you different graphs to different places then change the `ChartObjects` to `ChartObjects("NAME OF YOUR GRAPH")`, and move to to where ever you want.