# I created a macro but it did not follow my actions completely, is something wrong?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried creating a stacked chart with macro, however, it did not delete completely what I wanted. I only want the name of each column to be there and everything else gone and to be placed at `cell b13`. May I know what is wrong with the code?

[image: it shows this]

```
Sub utilisation()

    Dim chtChart As Chart

    Set chtChart = Charts.Add
    Set chtChart = chtChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1")

    With chtChart

        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked

        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a22:i23"), _
            PlotBy:=xlRows

        With chtChart

            .HasTitle = False
            .ChartTitle.Delete
            .Axes(xlCategory).Delete
            .Axes(xlValue).Delete
            .HasLegend = False
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
            .Axes(xlValue).MinorGridlines.Delete
            .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
            .ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: yes i switched it out however there are still errors edited in the quesiton above

Comment: Which line produces what error? What is your expected output?

Comment: it shows invalid procedure call and argument. error run time 5. it did not show me which line

Comment: Did you try the macro recorder?

Comment: yes I did, it did not work for me

Comment: You have two `With Statements` one in the other, both of them referring to the same object - `chtChart`

Comment: Trying your code I was getting error 9 (my Locale is Spanish, but it shouldn't matter).
See updated answer.

Comment: I've took hours and hours to figure it out and that's all you have to say. i'm sorry that i'm new and i'm asking so many questions. Guess these is me showing **no effort**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to delete the charttitle which you have just declared is likely what generated the error. At any rate it was where the macro stopped when I tried to run your code.

In addition having another with statement within your first one, is superfluous, although it doesn't generate an error for me.

The following code did what you seem to want, when I tried it out:

```
Option Explicit

Sub utilisation()

    Dim chtChart As Chart

    Set chtChart = Charts.Add
    Set chtChart = chtChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1")

    With chtChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a22:i23"), PlotBy:=xlRows

        .HasTitle = False
        .Axes(xlCategory).Delete
        .Axes(xlValue).Delete
        .HasLegend = False
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorGridlines.Delete
        .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
        .ChartArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .PlotArea.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

        .Parent.Top = Sheet1.Range("B13").Top
        .Parent.Left = Sheet1.Range("B13").Left
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out, I have zero background of vba, was thrown this job by my boss out of the blue. I learnt almost everything on youtube.This code really helped me out a lot! was cracking my brains and finding for solutions for hours.

Answer (score -1):

To set the location of a chart, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028840/2707864) (replicating here for convenience):

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 66")
    .Left = Range("B13").Left
    .Top = Range("B13").Top
End With
```

As for what you want to have removed from your chart, it is not clear.

(Perhaps suited for a comment, but comments do not have enough formatting capabilities so it would read somewhat garbled).

**As per OP update**:
Removing one of the two `With chtChart` I do not get any error.

Comment: I've come up with a new vba code maybe it might be clearer edited in my question. it always stop working when i tried deleting attributes in the chart